# How to add value to default summary fields in google cloud log explorer

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I am currently trying to clean my google cloud log explorer and want to add summary fields to show up **by default** in the explorer like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrzSy.png]

My desired effect can be achieved by setting custom summary fields to show label values, but I want this behaviour by default.

Current code being used to generate the log:

```
from google.cloud import logging_v2

def write_entry(logger_name):
    """Writes log entries to the given logger."""
    logging_client = logging_v2.Client(project="test-project")

    # This log can be found in the Cloud Logging console under 'Custom Logs'.
    logger = logging_client.logger("TEST",labels={"label1":"I want this to show in default summary field"})

    # Make a simple text log
    logger.log_text("Hello, world!")

    print("Wrote logs to {}.".format(logger.name))

write_entry("test-log-bucket")
```

I would like the log entry `label1` value in `labels` to be shown where the circle is in the provided image.

All help and guidance is appreciated.

Comment: @bpereira Sadly not. I have fallen back to just using labels as custom summary fields as shown in my example above.